# Take output from AWK command and display line by line based on white space

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am running the following command in a bash script:

```
 echo `netstat -plten | grep -i autossh | awk '{print $4}'` >> /root/logs/autossh.txt
```

The output displays in a single line:

```
127.0.0.1:25001 127.0.0.1:15501 127.0.0.1:10001 127.0.0.1:20501 127.0.0.1:15001 127.0.0.1:5501 127.0.0.1:20001
```

I would like each IP to display line by line. What do I need to do with the awk command to make the output display line by line

Comment: Why did you add an `echo` and backticks?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `echo` and subshell:

```
netstat -plten | grep -i autossh | awk '{print $4}' >> /root/logs/autossh.txt
```

`awk` is already printing them one per line, but when you pass them to `echo` it parses its arguments and prints them each with a space between them.  Every line of `awk` output then becomes a separate argument to `echo` so you lose your line endings.

Of course, `awk` can do pattern matching too, so no real need for `grep`:

```
netstat -plten | awk '/autossh/ {print $4}' >> /root/logs/autossh.txt
```

with `gawk` at least you can have it ignore case too

```
netstat -plten | awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} /autossh/ {print $4}' >> /root/logs/autossh.txt
```

or as Ed Morton pointed out, with any `awk` you could do

```
netstat -plten | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /autossh/ {print $4}' >> /root/logs/autossh.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just quote the result of command substitution to prevent the shell from performing word splitting.

You can modify it as follows to achieve what you want.

```
echo "`netstat -plten | grep -i autossh | awk '{print $4}'`" >> /root/logs/autossh.txt
```